# Cache videos in view controller using plugin

Tags: ios, swift, caching

I started learning swift a few weeks ago and I am now moving on to something a little trickier: I would like to build a simple app which uses a `UIPageViewController`. Each page shall contain a video which is loaded from a server using a plugin called [Player](https://github.com/piemonte/Player). Since I want individual videos to be player on the pages, I use an array which stores all the URLs. These URLs are then used to set a value in another class. If the value in this class was set (`didSet`), I load the video using the plugin. All that works perfectly fine! To get an idea of what I did you can click this link to [this youtube tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OopGGyHKHlU&t=1400s) which I used as an orientation.

However, I encountered a problem which I had already suspected: The videos are *reloaded* whenever one hits a page one has already been on and the video has already been loaded on once. Obviously, I don't want the videos to reload every time which is why I looked for a caching library for swift under [awesome-swift](https://github.com/Wolg/awesome-swift). The first one suggested (HanekeSwift) somehow didn't work for me and gave me a bunch of errors every time I tried to include it. Thus, I tried to approach my problem using the second option provided: [Carlos](https://github.com/WeltN24/Carlos) which didn't cause any errors (which is a library by a German news agency so it sounds and also looks very professional). Nevertheless, as I am quite new to swift, I cannot quite put my finger on this plugin. I don't understand a lot of things since I am quite new...

What would I have to add to my code to cache the videos? Do I need to create another class for that? How would you recommend me to do it? I'll provide what i have till now below... And sorry for the long (and newby) question but I really couldn't figure it out.

## Code

### PageViewController

```
//viewDidLoad
override func viewDidLoad() {

    super.viewDidLoad()

    //set datasourcee to self for now
    dataSource = self

    view.backgroundColor = .white

    let postViewController = PostViewController()
    postViewController.video = videos.first
    let viewControllers = [postViewController]

    //set first view controller
    setViewControllers(viewControllers, direction: .forward, animated: true, completion: nil)

}

//videos array
let videos = ["https://link.to/testvideo.mov", "https://link.to/testvideo.mov", "https://link.to/testvideo.mov", "https://link.to/testvideo.mov"]

//after page
func pageViewController(_ pageViewController: UIPageViewController, viewControllerAfter viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController? {

    let currentIndexString  = (viewController as! PostViewController).index
    let currentIndex        = indec.index(of: currentIndexString!)

    //next page possible?
    if currentIndex! < indec.count - 1 {

        let postViewController = PostViewController()
        postViewController.video            = videos[currentIndex! + 1]

        return postViewController

    }

    return nil

}

//before page
func pageViewController(_ pageViewController: UIPageViewController, viewControllerBefore viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController? {

    let currentIndexString  = (viewController as! PostViewController).index
    let currentIndex        = indec.index(of: currentIndexString!)

    //previous page possible?
    if currentIndex! > 0 {

        //template
        let postViewController = PostViewController()
        postViewController.video            = videos[currentIndex! - 1]

        return postViewController

    }

    return nil

}
```

### PostViewController

```
var video:String? {

    didSet {

        print(video ?? String())
        setupPlayer()

    }

}

//orienting myself by the example provided by "Player" plugin from here on (https://github.com/piemonte/Player/blob/master/Project/Player/ViewController.swift)
fileprivate var player = Player()

deinit {

    self.player.willMove(toParentViewController: self)
    self.player.view.removeFromSuperview()
    self.player.removeFromParentViewController()

}

override func viewDidLoad() {

    super.viewDidLoad()

    view.backgroundColor = .blue

}

func setupPlayer() {

    self.view.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleWidth, .flexibleHeight]

    self.player.playerDelegate = self as? PlayerDelegate
    self.player.playbackDelegate = self as? PlayerPlaybackDelegate
    self.player.view.frame = self.view.bounds

    self.addChildViewController(self.player)
    self.view.addSubview(self.player.view)
    self.player.didMove(toParentViewController: self)

    self.player.url = URL(string: video!)

    self.player.playbackLoops = true

}
```